# ng-class expression only evaluates scope property once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-class

I have 2 divs with an ng-class applied to evaluate a $scope property, called {{stepNumber}}.

```
 <div id="step0" class="col-xs-2" ng-class="{{stepNumber}} == 0 ? 'active' : {{stepNumber}} > 1 ? 'complete' : 'disabled' ">

 <div id="step1" class="col-xs-2" ng-class="{{stepNumber}} == 1 ? 'active' : {{stepNumber}} > 1 ? 'complete' : 'disabled' ">
```

The first time the page is loaded, `{{stepNumber}} is 0`,

1st div gets class *active*, 2nd div gets class *disabled*.

When I click a button that uses *ng-click* to increment the property value by doing `$scope.stepNumber++;`, the divs do not reevaluate the ng-class expression.

{{stepNumber}} is now 1 but the 1st div class is **still** *active*, 2nd div class is **still** *disabled*

How can I get the ng-class to reevaluate the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how ng-class works. Read [its documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) carefully. The correct code would be:

```
ng-class="{active: stepNumber == 0, complete: stepNumber > 1, disabled: stepNumber != 0 && stepNumber <= 1}"
```

or

```
class="col-xs-2, {{stepNumber == 0 ? 'active' : stepNumber > 1 ? 'complete' : 'disabled' }}"
```

or

```
ng-class="stepNumber == 0 ? 'active' : stepNumber > 1 ? 'complete' : 'disabled'"
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have read more closely. I didn't realized I didn't need the {{}} with ng-class.  Thank you so much.